# Pay later for membership by PayPal?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, paypal, ipn

Here's the scenario:

- we are using civicrm 4.6 with Wordpress
- we want to accept payments for membership via PayPal
- we don't want to take payment until membership request approved

So basically we want to accept membership applications that remain as Pending and then when we accept them we request PayPal payment to be made.

Any ideas?

I've created contribution page with 'pay later' option. This works great in that individual record and membership are created with status Pending. There is even an option to then manually record a payment to complete membership- but not via PayPal!

Now I don't know much about PayPal and IPN, but would it be feasible to have PayPal as a manual 'pay later' option that when invoked fired off email to customer asking them to make PayPal payment using a specific URL provided (or reference) and then PayPal via IPN notifies CiviCRM on success and membership then set to active? I'm guessing CiviCRM must have a PayPal 'listener' but does this only listen for responses made to request directly made from CiviCRM to start with or can responses come one way from PayPal to complete a transaction?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: question updated to hopefully be clearer

Answer (score 2):

A complete sidestep would be to use a standalone Profile for submitting the membership 'application' and then when approved fire them an email with checksum to the Contribution page which has the membership optionsn on it, which uses the paypal payment processor so you get paid and creates the membership. just a thought.

Comment: Many thanks for reply. Your answer seems to be implying what I thought might be possibe, I'm just not sure of how too implement this. When you say the 'payment page' do you mean a page we create for this purpose or do you mean direct them to PayPal page? I'm presuming the latter and that 'checksum' is encoded info for PayPal to handle payment and then communicate back to CiviCRM listender to handle membership? If I'm on the right track how do we go about creating checksum to fire off in the email to customer?

Comment: By 'payment page' i meant the Contribution page which you set up with Membership options - and which will in your case use the PayPal payment processor

Comment: I don't follow. If I have 'payment later' on my contribution page (I can't have PayPal as I don't want payments made immediately) then how can users be directed back to that same page in the future? i.e. it will still be set to 'pay later' and therefore have no means to initiate PayPal payment.

Comment: I was avoiding that by suggesting you just use a Profile ie not a Contribution page, to get their 'application'. Then when it is approved you send them to the membership/contribution page to do the payment. sorry if that is adding confusion for you but it seemed like a workable alternative

Comment: i edited my answer in the hope that it is a bit clearer

Comment: Problem is application details are quite extensive i.e. 3 levels, two of which are membership on behalf of an organisation, 3 pricing sets, as well as lot of extra information i.e. I'm loading profile top and bottom + the onbehalf of one. As far as know I can't collect information on multiple profiles tied together outside of contribution page format? i.e. auto create organisation record plus individual record?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34335/discussion-between-redactuk-and-petednz-fuzion).